# detect pixel brightness changes in camera preview of Android

Tags: android, screen-brightness

Anyone have idea how we can measure the light intensity/brightness of pixels in camera preview?
Foe example: some objects able to absorb light resulting in lower average brightness value.

Hopefully, someone want to share some good article/documentation.

Thanks for any help.